# How to output continously CPU usage of a specific process into a text file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am planning to write a PowerShell or batch script which writes the CPU usage of a process continuously into a text file. I am new to Windows, have worked on bash before. I am struggling with below batch script.

Can someone help me with it?

I even checked Sysinternals' `PsList`, however not sure which one to use.

```
for /f "skip=2 tokens=2 delims=," %%c in ('typeperf "\Process(java.exe)\%% Processor Time" -sc 1') do (
    set cpu_usage=%%~c
    goto :break
)
```

Comment: You should look at the output for `typeperf /?` because you don't need any sort of loop at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra percent sign in processor. You don't specify `.exe` either. This shows CMD.exe.

```
:MyLabel
typeperf "\Process(cmd)\% Processor Time" -sc 1 >> MyLogFile
Goto MyLabel
```